# route and $scope variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I having a few problems with my codes, I created an module `demoApp` example, following:

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <title>Customer - Order Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

            demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                        .when('/order',
                                {
                                    controller: 'UserController',
                                    templateUrl: 'partials/order.html'
                                })
                        .when('/user', 
                                {
                                    controller: 'UserController',
                                    templateUrl: 'partials/user.html'
                                })
                       .otherwise({redirectTo: '/user'});

            });

            demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', function() {
                var orders = [{id: 1, title: 'Order1', quantity: 10, user_id: 1},
                                  {id: 2, title: 'Order2', quantity: 10, user_id: 1},
                                  {id: 3, title: 'Order3', quantity: 10, user_id: 1},
                                  {id: 4, title: 'Order1', quantity: 10, user_id: 2},
                                  {id: 5, title: 'Order1', quantity: 10, user_id: 2},
                                  {id: 6, title: 'Order1', quantity: 10, user_id: 2}];
                var factory = {};
                factory.getOrders = function() {
                    return orders;
                };

                return factory;

            });

            demoApp.controller('UserController', function($scope, simpleFactory){
                $scope.users = [{id: 1, name: 'User1', email: 'user1@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 2, name: 'User2', email: 'user2@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 3, name: 'User3', email: 'user3@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 4, name: 'User4', email: 'user4@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 5, name: 'User5', email: 'user5@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 6, name: 'User6', email: 'user6@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 7, name: 'User7', email: 'user7@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 8, name: 'User8', email: 'user8@yopmail.com', age: 27},
                                {id: 9, name: 'User9', email: 'user9@yopmail.com', age: 27}];

                $scope.orders = simpleFactory.getOrders();


                $scope.addUser = function()
                {
                    $scope.users.push({id: $scope.users.length, name: $scope.newName, email: $scope.newEmail, age: $scope.newAge});
                };

                $scope.ordersOfUser = [];

                $scope.redirectOrder = function(userId)
                {
                    angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(value, key){

                        if(value.user_id ===  userId)
                        {
                            $scope.ordersOfUser.push(value);
                        }

                    });
                    return $scope.ordersOfUser;
                };

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but I dont know why the `orderOfUser` is empty when I invoked it in the `order.html` template file..

order.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Quanity</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="order in ordersOfUser">
            <tr>
                <td>{{order.title}}</td>
                <td>{{order.quantity}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a ng-href="#/user" /> Back to user </a>
</div>
```

user.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <form ng-submit="addUser()">
        <label for="name"> Name </label>
        <input ng-model="newName" />
        <label for="name"> Email </label>
        <input ng-model="newEmail" />
        <label for="name"> Age </label>
        <input ng-model="newAge" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
        <li>
            <p>{{user.name}}</p>
            <p>{{user.email}}</p>
            <p>{{user.age}}</p>
            <a ng-href="#/order" ng-click="redirectOrder(user.id)">Order</a>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As for as I can see you have 2 separate instances of `UserController`.  So, the `ng-click` will populate `ordersOfUser` in one controller scope (and will not be available in the other).  Controllers are not singletons like services, factories and providers.

Answer (score 1):

It's blank because you never populate it:

```
$scope.ordersOfUser = [];
```

The only code that touches this field is the `$scope.redirectOrder` function, which is never called.

**EDIT after your comment**

You are using the same controller for both routes. This means that when you change routes, the controller will be re-instantiated. As such, when you navigate from `/user` to `/order`, this line gets called again:

```
$scope.ordersOfUser = [];
```

This is called **after** your `redirectOrder` function, so it clears everything out.

What you should do instead is use a **service** to store this sort of information, then inject that into two separate controllers, one for the orders page and one for the users page.

Comment: Thank you Ed for relying but I invoked  $scope.redirectOrder in user.html file : <a ng-href="#/order" ng-click="redirectOrder(user.id)">Order</a>. Pls help me. Thank again

Comment: @bunle-o Can you include the `ng-click` in the question?  Can you confirm that the function is called using `console.log`?

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks Davin I have just add the content of user.html file. Could you pls take a look it. Thank again